# XMLMapper: how do I serialize CDATA wrapped values?

Tags: swift, xmlmapper

CDATA deserialization works great out of the box. But how should I configure this mapping:

```
class MyData: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    var cdataValue: String?
    ...
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        cdataValue <- map.attributes["cdataValue"]
    }
}
```

and when I call `toXMLString()`:

```
let myData = MyData()
myData.cdataValue = "actualValue"
print(myData.toXMLString())
```

to eventually obtain something like this:

```
<cdataValue><![CDATA[ actualValue ]]></cdataValue>
```

Comment: Actually, this is something that I didn't thought of when I created XMLMapper. You can open an issue in the Github repository. I will try to find a solution and release a new version. Thank you.